# How to allow mounting LUKS volume as non-root user?

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, mount

Clicking a LUKS-encrypted volume in a graphical file manager I have to first enter the encryption password and then the user password to complete the mount. How do I allow mounting LUKS volumes once within a window manager (*not* at boot) without elevating privileges to root? That is, without having to enter my login password.

Comment: Isn't that what you've just described you doing?

Comment: @roaima I guess OP needs the user password to elevate privileges with `sudo`.

Comment: @pLumo I can see that, but the description seems to be exactly what's required to "_allow mounting LUKS volumes at will_". Note that that question didn't ask how to avoid entering passwords.

Comment: You're right, the question is not 100% clear. But with Nautilus/Nemo you can mount without `sudo`, I guess it's using `gvfs`/`gio` or `fuse` or so in the background. The answer could be how to do that in Thunar (or maybe on Terminal).

Comment: @pLumo it could, indeed, but it seems the OP is asking about thunar rather than the command line

Comment: @roaima, I've clarified. The language gets incredibly stilted when trying to use the abstract terms for everything.

Comment: Thanks. It should be possible to set it up without you needing to enter a password (I just don't know how... yet).

Answer (score 1):

You could try a helper program. Something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Configuration parameters.  Change to fit your site.
   Some of these must be string constants.  String pasting is used. */
#define UUID "b3b7bd7b-4f00-4848-8af9-33a56f0b8a97"
#define NAME "cryptdisk"
#define MOUNTPOINT "/mnt/1"
/* The next line is optional.  If specified, the user won't even be
   prompted for the encrypted disk password. */
/* #define KEY_FILE "/root/disk_key_file" */


/* Replacement environment, for safety */
char * replacement_environment[] = {
    "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin",
    "HOME=/root",
    "TERM=dumb",
    0
};

void run(char *exec, ...)
{
    #define MAXARGS 20
    char *args[MAXARGS];
    char *arg;
    int count = 0;
    va_list ap;
    
    args[count++] = exec;
    va_start(ap, exec);
    while ((count < MAXARGS) && (arg = va_arg(ap, char *))) {
        args[count++] = arg;
    }
    if (count >= MAXARGS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many arguments\n");
        exit(127);
    }
    args[count++] = 0;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork error");
            exit(127);

        case 0:
            execve(exec, args, replacement_environment);
            perror("exec error");
            exit(127);

        default:
        {
            pid_t wpid;
            int status;
            for (;;) {
                wpid = wait(&status);
                if (wpid == -1) {
                    perror("wait error");
                    exit(127);
                }
                if (pid == wpid) break;
            }
            if (status != 0) {
                if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) 
                    fprintf(stderr, "Child %s terminated with signal %d\n", exec, WTERMSIG(status));
                else if (WIFEXITED(status))
                    fprintf(stderr, "Child %s exited with status %d\n", exec, WEXITSTATUS(status));
                else
                    fprintf(stderr, "Child %s exited with result %d\n", exec, status);
                exit(126);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void do_mount(void)
{
    setreuid(0,0);
#ifdef KEY_FILE
    run("/sbin/cryptsetup", "--key-file", KEY_FILE, "luksOpen", "UUID="UUID, NAME, NULL);
#else
    run("/sbin/cryptsetup", "luksOpen", "UUID="UUID, NAME, NULL);
#endif
    run("/bin/mount", "/dev/mapper/"NAME, MOUNTPOINT, NULL);
}

void do_umount(void)
{
    setreuid(0,0);
    run("/bin/umount", MOUNTPOINT, 0);
    run("/sbin/cryptsetup", "luksClose", NAME, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char const *prog = argv[0];
    char const *last_slash = strrchr(prog, '/');
    if (last_slash) prog = last_slash+1;
    if (prog[0] == 'u') 
        do_umount();
    else
        do_mount();
    exit(0);
}
```

You will need to change the configuration values near the top.
If you need to further tweak the cryptsetup arguments, that should be fairly obvious.
As for how to tie this into "`Thunar`", I can't help you there.

Build something like:

```
gcc -o mount_it mount_it.c
sudo chown root mount_it
sudo chmod u+s mount_it
ln -s mount_it umount_it
```

Comment: Yes it works! (Don't forget chmod u+s after recompiling..!)